# scala: how to create a generic type which is subtype of all the number classes in scala so that it can include compare method

Tags: generics, scala

I am trying to create a generic class with generic type being subclass of Numeric (to ensure that I am dealing with numbers.)
and I tried "`class NuVector[T<:Numeric[T])`" as class def and it compiling fine.

Now I want to add `PartiallyOrdered[T]` to it. so I did the following:

```
class NuVector[T<:Numeric[T]) extends PartiallyOrdered[T]
{

 /** Array that stores the vector values.
     */
    val v = new Array [T] (_length)
    /** Range for the storage array.
     */
    private val range = 0 to _length - 1

    def compare(x:T,y:T)(implicit res:Numeric[T]) :Int=
    { 
       res.compare(x,y) 
    } 

   def tryCompareTo [B >: NuVector [T]] (b: B)
        (implicit view$1: (B) => PartiallyOrdered [B]): Option [Int] =
    { 
        compare(x,y) 
    } 

    implicit def castT2Ordering(x:T):Numeric[T]=x.asInstanceOf[Numeric[T]]
    implicit def castB2NuVector [B>:NuVector[T]] (b:B): NuVector[T]=
    {
              b.asInstanceOf[NuVector[T]]
    }

}
```

it is not compiling. 
The error I am getting while compiling is:

```
 could not find implicit value for parameter res:Numeric[T]
```

Scala version I am using is 2.8

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
~Tiger.
I don't know whether it is a bug or its a problem with my definition.

Comment: What exact version of Scala2.8 are you using? And is this related with ticket 2274? ( http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/2274 )

Answer (score 7):

Scala's `Numeric[T]` uses the ["Typeclass Pattern"](http://rickyclarkson.blogspot.com/2009/01/typeclass-pattern.html). It doesn't really make sense to say `class NuVector[T <: Numeric[T]]`. What you want, instead, is `class NuVector[T](implicit n: Numeric[T])`.

Comment: And the shortcut for this is the "context bound" introduced in Scala 2.8: `class NuVector[T : Numeric]`. Where this `T` is in scope, the evidence parameter may be acquired using `val num = implicitly[Numeric[T]]`.

Answer (score 5):

even better, use `class NuVector[T:Numeric]`

This is also known as a context bound, and is just syntactic sugar for `class NuVector[T](implicit n: Numeric[T])`

where `n` is actually some synthetically-generated name that you can't access directly